# Using a Tablet as Input

Tags: tablet, graphics-tablet

I am considering getting a tablet to use on the go. But I also would like to use it in conjunction with my Laptop and Desktop PC, both running Ubuntu.

Specifically, I am imagining using it as an input device for graphics programmes, virtual blackboards and the like.

After a cursory search, this seems to be feasible in principle, but is there anything I should be aware before buying any tablet? Are different operating systems on the tablet better suited for this?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you intend to make your tablet the controller than I got a way to do it.

I will suggest you try it with your mobile phone first to ensure you get what you desired.

1. Go here an install [gs-connect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/) as an extension
   You will get the `Mobile Devices` column like below if everything is good

[image]

2. Install `KDE connect` in your tablet from the play store.
3. Connect your laptop with your phone via hotspot and then connect using KDE-connect

laptop:-
[image]

mobile:-

[image]

4. Go to plugin setting to enable plugins and permissions in KDE-connect in your mobile
5. Now go to `Remote-input` option in KDE-connect an enjoy  :)

Comment: While this is certainly a convenient method to control the computer, this may not be a good way to draw in programs, and write in virtual blackboards. You may want to add more info about Wacom Tablets and similar graphical tablets which support Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will try it asap. Achisman Panigrahi, could you tell me a few of the specifics you were thinking of?

Comment: I agree with you @Archisman Panigrahi  but for someone who wants to buy ipad‍♂️ this can be a easy option to go for. For a pro there are better choices

Comment: @Zersetzor There are certain tablets and writing pads by Wacom, which are primarily meant for writing in virtual blackboard and drawing, and Ubuntu supports many of these out of the box. With KDE Connect, it is hard to add fine details unless you have a stylus.

Note: I am **not** affiliated with Wacom.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Thanks for the clarification. I'm currently looking to get a regular pad and wanted to try it out for these kinds of things on top of the normal functions. If that doesn't work out or not as well as I hope, I'll look for more dedicated hardware.